# Background Location Updates in Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I find myself confused with the new background limitations and am just looking for some clarity here...

With the app in the foreground OR in the background with a foreground service running, background services are good to go.  I got this.

With the app in the background and without a foreground service, the background service is stopped by the system.  I'm cool with this as well.

My question:

The app can still obtain limited location updates per hour but **how**?  Where do you create the request so that it doesn't get eaten up by the system when the app is in the background?

Comment: Alarm manager with a request for location would probably work

Comment: `JobScheduler` would be even better, insofar as you have ~10 minutes instead of ~1 minute to get a location fix. It's also possible that they were envisioning using a `getForegroundService()` `PendingIntent` with the `PendingIntent`-flavored location update options. As usual, the documentation is less than completely enlightening.

Comment: @CommonsWare it's that issue with the documentation that brought me here.  The lack of 'how' has me running into walls.  Even with jobScheduler, will Oreo allow the triggered service to run long enough to get the location?

Comment: "will Oreo allow the triggered service to run long enough to get the location?" -- I would expect it to be subject to normal Android 8.0+ rules. If you are using a regular background `Service`, you will have ~1 minute. If you are using a `JobService`, you will have ~10 minutes. Either should be adequate to get a fix, barring environmental issues that might preclude getting a fix entirely (e.g., device is in a parking garage), though I'd lean towards the `JobScheduler` approach. IOW, I'm not aware that the background work gets special treatment just because it is working with location APIs.

Comment: This new feature is so bad that even Google Map's location sharing feature become useless, I can no longer get friend's current location. Probably no one can request for background location update. Better ask the Oreo's team to fix this "feature"